# 8 pin connector identification

Tags: identification, power-connector

I need to create an extension so this without modifying it. What connector is this, so I can find and purchase more of these connections?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Get another machine and take the connectors off that.

Comment: I'm answering this question as a product identification question, which is allowed on this site, but note that as written, it's a "where do i buy this" question, which is not allowed on this site. You may want to alter the wording a bit.

Comment: Can you (1) describe where that connector comes from / what it's used for, and (2) take a picture (or pictures) that _clearly_ shows which of the pins are square, and which have the corners bevelled (and which corners)? It vaguely resembles the "PCIe 8-pin" (or "GPU") power connector, or the "EPS-12V" power connector, both of which are standard on PC power supplies. But I'm not sure it's actually either one of them. They are both 8-pin "Molex-style" connectors like this, but each one has a slightly different keying on the pins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks to be a very standard computer power connector, of the type originally made by Molex (under the series name Mini-Fit Jr), and now made by several manufacturers. Many people simply call them Molex connectors. [Here's](https://www.mouser.com/Connectors/Headers-Wire-Housings/Mini-Fit-Jr/_/N-ay0lo?P=1yilv2f) a large selection of them.

[image]

([image source](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Molex/46992-0810?qs=UxK%2FDTs6dB4M3iMMJn7Dwg%3D%3D))

Comment: But if you're looking for a GPU power cable, the housing is slightly different. Very difficult to find. I tried.

Comment: @DKNguyen That's interesting; slightly different in what way? Is it keyed?

Comment: I think the pin shrouds are different on some pins so some form of keying.

Comment: @DKNguyen The standard Mini-Fit connectors are each keyed so any other pin configuration of the connector from the same series won't fit into the "wrong" one (with a larger or smaller number of contacts). The PCIe GPU power connector variants are unusual in that the 3x2 ones _do_ fit in the 4x2 sockets and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of these connectors but that one appears to be keyed, possibly a GPU.

[Molex Micro-fit](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/molex,-llc/0430250800/252499?utm_adgroup=Connectors%2C%20Interconnectors&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Shopping_Supplier_Molex_0900_Co-op&utm_term=&productid=252499&gclid=CjwKCAjwjJmIBhA4EiwAQdCbxigTGiW2bSonpXhqI4jNmiCszYnFORog_ciBiKZjs2UoXXyv_cOEdxoC6e4QAvD_BwE)

[image]